# How to convert int to date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I am using MS SQL Server 2008,
and in a table I have column idate as date but in the integer format.
But in the query I want that in the date format.
Is it possible to convert integer date into proper datetime format?

Comment: When you say that you have a date in integer format, what exactly do you mean - what is the format?

Comment: davey is correct. `DATEADD(DAY, 40835, '1900-01-01')` is slightly faster in tests I have run.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can't convert an integer value straight to a date but you can first it to a datetime then to a date type

`select cast(40835 as datetime)`

and then convert to a date (SQL 2008)

`select cast(cast(40835 as datetime) as date)`

cheers

Comment: just reread your question, if want as a date time then just do select cast(40835 as datetime)

Comment: I had to subtract 2 days off my integer value (from excel) to get the correct date, e.g. select cast(40835-2 as datetime)

Answer (score 4):

You have to first convert it into datetime, then to date.

Try this, it might be helpful:

```
Select Convert(DATETIME, LEFT(20130101, 8))
```

then convert to date.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to examine the documentation for T-SQL's **CAST and CONVERT** functions, located in the documentation here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187928(v=SQL.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187928%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx)

You will then use one of those functions in your T-SQL query to convert the [idate] column from the database into the datetime format of your liking in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Reading through this helps solve a similar problem. The data is in decimal datatype - [DOB] [decimal](8, 0) NOT NULL - eg - 19700109. I want to get at the month. The solution is to combine SUBSTRING with CONVERT to VARCHAR.

```
    SELECT [NUM]
       ,SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DOB),5,2) AS mob
    FROM [Dbname].[dbo].[Tablename]
```