# DateTime convert in SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, datetime

I have DateTime saved as Integer in row of table in format 20111111.
I want to display it by select to : 2011-11-11.

Please give me some as simpliest solution.

The `Datetime` is in table and looks like:

```
Table_name
20111212
20111113
20111212
```

and i want to display it like

```
Table_name
2011-12-12
2011-11-13
2011-12-12
```

MS SQL Server 2012

Comment: Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855867/convert-int-to-datetime-sql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830002/how-to-convert-int-to-date-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by:

```
CONVERT(date, CAST(dbo.database_name.table_name AS CHAR(12)), 112) AS table_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
declare @a int
    set @a ='20111212'

    select stuff(stuff(@a,len(@a)-3,0,'-'),len(@a)-0,0,'-')

    --> 2011-12-12
```

[fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/757ef/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to `varchar`, then to `datetime`, then use [`CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) with the proper style:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(CAST(20111111 AS VARCHAR(10))AS DATETIME), 120)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1415c/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CONVERT(varchar, Year(column)) +'_' + CONVERT(varchar, Month(column)) +'_'+ 
  CONVERT(varchar, Date(column))
```