# Int to Date in SQL SERVER 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to convert an int column ,Birthdate( sample value 20090301) to a date column in the format(01/03/2009)
Sql Server 2000

I was trying to convert some thing like below

```
select * from tabl
where 
cast(dob as datetime)>='01/03/2009'
which gives an error

Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime.
```

Comment: You don't want to do that. You want to convert the input `'01/03/2009'` to int `20090301` so you can use the index you have on `dob` to find the rows you want really fast.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830002/how-to-convert-int-to-date-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't allow you to cast int -> datetime directly, but if you're sure you can cast it to nvarchar first and then cast it to date.
For your question here's an example

```
declare @test int = 20090301
select CONVERT(datetime, CAST(@test as nvarchar), 112)
```

112 is the format you mentioned, [here's the list](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) of all possible formats for Convert function.

Answer (score 1):

try this !

```
select * from tabl
where 
cast(convert(char(8),dob, 112) as date)>='2009-03-01'
```

Comment: Perhaps because there is no datatype `date` in SQL Server 2000. Or it could be because you are applying a function on a column in a where clause which will make the expression non-sargable.