# How to convert int to datetime with hours and minutes with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm using two databases and I've got a problem.

One uses date with `datetime` datatype, while the other one uses `int` (201901010000 for example).

I want to compare them and it needs to be fast, I've tried so far :

- `convert(date, 21)` or other numbers (my `datetime` is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SSSS`) but it doesn't work with minutes and hours.
- I tried to delete all the '-' and ':' from the datetime and then convert to int

So my question is simple, how to compare it efficiently?

Thank you =)

Comment: `201901010000` will not fit in an `INT`. What's the *actual* type used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Int to Date in SQL SERVER 2000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297724/int-to-date-in-sql-server-2000)

Comment: You can compare the date values by using a LEFT(DateValue,10).

Comment: Yes it's not an INT you are right it's a numeric, i need to compare with the hours and minutes

Comment: Comparing an `(big)int` to a `datetime` is never going to be fast, as the datatypes aren't comparable. If you want speed to you're going to want to add a persisted computed column to *at least* one of the tables to translate the value from the one data type to the other, and then (for evern better performance) index it.

Comment: Yes but there aren't my databases .

Comment: @Fabieng the comparison will never be fast because you have to *convert* the number into a date before it can be used. Any index that covers that column will be useless. Either add a computed column or copy the data to a temporary table/staging database with the correct types

Comment: So how do i compare the int to datetime including the minutes and hours ?

Comment: If you can't make changes to the tables themselves (such as adding a persisted computed column) then you aren't going to get a fast query. Like I said, `(big)int` (or `numeric`, as it seems the datatype actually is) and `datetime` are not comparable datatypes so a query between the 2 would be as fast as a scan of both tables.

Comment: @Fabient you'll have to convert the bigint into a date, no matter how you end up comparing the values. The link provided by APH is one solution. Another one is to use [DATEFROMPARTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or DATETIMEFROMPARTS with some integer arithmetic to convert the bigint into years, month, day etc

Comment: @Fabient another option since SQL Server 2012 would be to convert the bigint to varchar(12) and use [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to parse it into a date, eg `FORMAT(cast(thatField as varchar(12)),'yyyyMMddhhmm')`

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(12, 0), FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMddHHmm'))` will convert a `DATETIME` to a `NUMERIC`, but, as has been pointed out by others, getting fast comparisons out of it tends to be tricky. (This approach is likely still faster than the reverse, converting the `NUMERIC` to a `DATETIME`, as that requires more operations, but it all depends on where you do the comparisons and which table has more rows -- you always want to have the type match the source column.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the below expressions to do the `JOIN` (not saying this is pretty at all). As per the comments I made in under the question, however, neither are going to perform well.

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(numeric,'201901010000'))) N(Dt)
     JOIN (VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2019-01-01T00:00:00'))) D(dt) ON CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(varchar(12),N.dt),11,0,':'),9,0,'T'),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-') + ':00.000') = D.Dt;

SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(CONVERT(numeric,'201901010000'))) N(Dt)
     JOIN (VALUES(CONVERT(datetime,'2019-01-01T00:00:00'))) D(dt) ON  N.Dt = CONVERT(numeric,LEFT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20),CONVERT(datetime,D.Dt),126),'-',''),'T',''),':',''),12));
```

Unless you can change the datatype of one of the columns (i.e. via a computed column) there's .little you can do about the performance, as the query in non-SARGable.