# Converting Integer to Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert an integer datatype into a date.  Here is the coding that I have so far:

```
SELECT CONVERT(column_name, yyyymm) from table_name;
```

What do I need to add?

Comment: What SQL database engine are you using?

Comment: This would be SQL Server 2012.

Comment: what is in ´column_name´? number of days since a date?

Comment: Duplicate Question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830002/how-to-convert-int-to-date-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: I receivied an error message:Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed.

Comment: Aye, but what does the int *look* like? Is it `ddmmyy`, `yyyymm`, seconds since the birth of Elvis?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your integer column (say, your_column) is representing year and month in `yyyymm` format, this should work.

First, convert your `int` column to a `varchar` and then add '01' to make it `yyyymmdd` (ISO Format), then convert to `datetime/date`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(6), your_column) + '01') myDate
FROM TableName
```

Comment: How can I do two conversions in a single select statement?

Comment: How can I convert it first to a varchar and then to an int in the same select statement?

Comment: @user3109653 Huh? Did you look at the sample code in the answer? Why do you think there is an issue performing two conversions in a single statement?

Comment: I tried using your code.  There seems to be just a small problem.  I receieved an error message saying that there was a problem converting from the varchar to a date.  Any idea why that might be?

Comment: Nevermind.  It worked after I deleted the + '01'.  Thank you very much.  Do you have any idea how I could format it?  Now I just have nubmers and dashes.  How could I include a three-letter month abbreviation instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
select DateAdd(second, someNbrCol, '1970-01-01')
```

The last argument you would have to provide as the starting date.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, convert(char(8),20180521))
```

or

```
select FORMAT(CONVERT (date,convert(char(8),20180521)),'dd-MMM-yyyy')
```